# How to fill a matrix using an equation in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix `A` of arbitrary dimensions `m` x `n` and wish to fill it using an equation, for example, for every element a_ij of `A`, i = 1,...,m and j=1,...,n, I would like,

a_ij = i^2 + j^2.

In Matlab filled out manually it would appear similar to this,

```
A = [1^2+1^2, 1^2+2^2, ..., 1^2+j^2, ..., 1^2+n^2;
     2^2+1^2, 2^2+2^2, ..., 2^2+j^2, ..., 2^2+n^2;

     .
     .
     .

     i^2+1^2, i^2+2^2, ..., i^2+j^2, ..., i^2+n^2;

     .                                       
     .
     .

     m^2+1^2, m^2+2^2, ..., m^2+j^2, ..., m^2+n^2]
```

and so the first few terms would be:

```
[2, 5, 10,17,...

 5, 8, 13,20,...

 10,13,18,25,...

 17,20,25,32,...
]
```

Comment: They both worked great. Thank you all. Also, sorry, I am new to MATLAB and this forum. I thought I set an email alert to know a question was asked by apparently not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative using `ndgrid`:

```
[I, J] = ndgrid(1:m, 1:n);
A = I.^2 + J.^2;
```

Comment: Equals: `A = ndgrid(1:n,1:m)'.^2+ndgrid(1:m,1:n).^2`

Comment: @A.Klomp Agreed but it's harder to read and likely to be less efficient than the `bsxfun` solution

Comment: Totally agree. Probably slower than the earlier ndgrid version as well, given that it calls it twice.

Comment: I can see that this method might not be as computationally efficient but I understand the code better than in the bsxfun and so I think it will serve me better for future equation inputs (as i^2 + j^2 isn't the only one I needed). Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 8):

**[`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html)** based solution -

```
A = bsxfun(@plus,[1:m]'.^2,[1:n].^2)
```

`bsxfun` performs `array expansion` on the `singleton dimensions` (i.e. dimensions with number of elements equal to 1) and performs an `elementwise operation specified by the function handle` 
which would be the first input argument to a `bsxfun` call.

So for our case, if we use a `column vector (mx1`) and a `row vector (1xn)`, then with the listed `bsxfun` code, both of these vectors would expand as `2D matrices` and would perform `elementwise summation of elements` (because of the function handle - @plus), giving us the desired 2D output. All of these steps are executed internally by MATLAB.

Note: This has to be pretty efficient with runtime performance, as `bsxfun` is well-suited for these `expansion` related problems by its very definition as described earlier.

Comment: [tag:bsxfun] is so much FUN!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is a nice neat formulation but I don't really understand what the equation/function means or is telling MATLAB to do. What is the @plus for please?

Comment: @josh See if the edits make a little more sense? `bsxfun` takes a bit of time to get hang of it, but it pays off with good performance improvements on vectorizable codes.

Comment: I think I understand that much better now. The bsxfun does the elementwise operation on the two vectors (which you've already squared) and you choose the operation, in this case @plus. I stupidly missed the ' to transpose when I was trying to break it down so didn't see how we had the (mx1) from the code [1:m]. Many thanks again! :)

Comment: @josh Yeah I guess I missed out on that tiny bit of info that `mx1` comes from the transpose of (1:m). Glad it finally made sense to you! `bsxfun` rules, try it more! :)