# How to vectorize a function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, loops, optimization, vectorization, user-defined-functions

Suppose I have a function

[image]

and that I'm interested in running over a grid of values of *q* and *w*. Here is my code in MATLAB:

```
clc; clear;

qlength = 1000;
wlength = 100;

qvec = rand(qlength,1);
wvec = rand(wlength,1);
[wgrid,qgrid] = meshgrid(wvec,qvec);

f = @(w,q)(1+exp(-q^2*w^2)*w*(1+w*q^2));
results = f(wgrid,qgrid);
```

If you run it, you will find that the last line returns an error. I have 2 remedies: two nested loops and `arrayfun`. The loops make the code ugly and the `arrayfun` is actually slower than the loops. How can I rewrite the definition of `f` above to obtain a vectorized solution that should be faster than both existing remedies? Thank you.

Comment: Just replace all `*` with `.*` (element-wise product)` and all `^` with `.^` (element-wise power)

Comment: @Suever Amazing! It's working for this toy example. Lemme try it on my real problem. Thank you so much.

Comment: Just keep in mind that all dot operations (`.*`) are element-wise. If something works for scalars and you just want to do that for all corresponding elements, just with the element-wise option for all relevant operators.

Comment: @Suever I know about the dot thing but I was shaky in using it. I tried just now with the real code and the run time is reduced 4-fold. Thank you very much. If you don't mind, perhaps you can make a short answer, and I will accept to close this question.

Comment: You could replace `meshrgrid, ndgrid` codes with `bsxfun` for further performance boost. See few examples : [1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25162350/3293881) [2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25885889/3293881) [3](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27341488/3293881).

Comment: It's not worth an answer. You can leave it here but I'm going to mark as a duplicate since it's been answered many times before.

Comment: @Divakar That is ridiculous, another 4 fold reduction in computation time. Salute to you my man.

Comment: Salute `bsxfun` instead! ;)