# Check for pixel values in a neighborhood

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I'm trying to write a MATLAB script that does the following:

Given: pixel coordinates(x,y) for a .jpg image
Goal: Check, within a 5 pixel radius of given coordinates, if there is a pixel of a certain value.

For example, let's say I'm given the coordinates (100,100), then I want to check the neighborhood of (100,100) within my image for any pixels that are black (0,0,0). So perhaps, pixel (103, 100) and (104,100) might have the value (0,0,0).

**Current code**:

```
x_coord = uint32(coord(:,1));  
y_coord = uint32(coord(:,2));
count = 0;

for i = 1:length(x_coord)
    %(img(x,y) returns pixel value at that (x,y)
    %Note 0 = black. Indicating that, at that position, the image is just 
    % black 
    if img(x_coord(i),y_coord(i)) == 0 
        count = count + 1;
    end
end
```

It currently only checks at an exact location. Not in a local neighborhood. How to could I extend this?

**EDIT:** Also note, as long as there as at least one pixel in the neighborhood with the value, I increment count. I'm *not trying to enumerate* how many pixels in the neighborhood have that value, just *trying to find evidence* of at least one pixel that has that value.

EDIT:

Even though I am unable to identify an error with the code, I am not able to get the exact results I want. Here is the code I am using.

```
val = 0; %pixel value to check
N = 50; % neighbourhood radius

%2D grid of coordinates surrounding center coordinate
[R, C] = ndgrid(1 : size(img, 1), 1 : size(img, 2));

for kk = 1 : size(coord, 1)
    r = coord(kk, 1); c = coord(kk, 2); % Get pixel locations

    % mask of valid locations within the neighbourhood (avoid boundary problems)
    mask = (R - r).^2 + (C - c).^2 <= N*N;         

    pix = img(mask); % Get the valid pixels
    valid = any(pix(:) ~= val);
    % Add either 0 or 1 depending if we have found any matching pixels
    if(valid == 1)
        img = insertMarker(img, [r c], 'x', 'color', 'red', 'size', 10);
        imwrite(img, images(i).name,'tiff');
    end
    count = count + valid; 
end
```

Comment: So did any of our answers help?

Comment: Ah! No problem. Just wanted to make sure we understood your problem... but I guess I can see we did :) Good luck!

Comment: @rayryeng hey, I have posted some results. Any ideas?

Comment: `insertMarker` takes in `x, y` coordinates meaning that the column comes first and the row comes after. Flip the order: `[c, r]`

Comment: Even when I change that, it doesn't show up. Or rather, bottom line is that around that particular coordinate, the algorithm doesn't detect any white spots. In essence, it doesn't even enter that if statement.

Comment: Ah. That's because I messed up the convention for the coordinates. I thought the first column was rows and second were columns in your coordinate matrix. Can you confirm what the convention is? If it's what I think it is I need to slightly change my answer.

Comment: OK, it looks like I did mess up the conventions.  Let me modify my answer and let me know if that works.  Make sure you keep the `[c, r]` flip in `insertMarker` the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An easier way to do this would be to use indexing to grab a neighbourhood, then to check to see if any of the pixels in the neighbourhood have the value that you're looking for, use [`any`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/any.html) on a flattened version of this neighbourhood.  The trick with grabbing the right neighbourhood is to first generate a 2D grid of coordinates that span the entire dimensions of your image, then simply use the equation of a circle with the centre of it being each coordinate you are looking at and determine those locations that satisfy the following equation:

```
(x - a)^2 + (y - b)^2 <= N^2
```

`N` is the radius of the observation window, `(a, b)` is a coordinate of interest while `(x, y)` is a coordinate in the image.  Use [`meshgrid`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html) to generate the coordinates.

You would use the above equation to create a `logical` mask, index into your image to pull the locations that are valid within the mask and check how many pixels match the one you want. Another added benefit with the above approach is that you are not subject to any out of bounds errors.  Because you are pre-generating the list of all valid coordinates in your image, generating the mask will confine you within the boundaries of the image so you never have to check for out of boundaries conditions.... even when you specify coordinates to search that are out of bounds.

Specifically, assuming your image is stored in `img`, you would do:

```
count = 0; % Remembers total count of pixels matching a value
val = 0; % Value to match
N = 50; % Radius of neighbourhood

% Generate 2D grid of coordinates
[x, y] = meshgrid(1 : size(img, 2), 1 : size(img, 1));

% For each coordinate to check...
for kk = 1 : size(coord, 1)
    a = coord(kk, 1); b = coord(kk, 2); % Get the pixel locations
    mask = (x - a).^2 + (y - b).^2 <= N*N; % Get a mask of valid locations
                                           % within the neighbourhood        
    pix = img(mask); % Get the valid pixels
    count = count + any(pix(:) == val); % Add either 0 or 1 depending if 
                                        % we have found any matching pixels
end
```

Comment: Nice one. I didn't know `ndgrid` before. I was stuck with the old-school way :).

Comment: @Anthony :D to be fair I used to use `repmat` to create a grid of coordinates.  Stack Overflow (and answering questions) has taught me better.

Comment: [`bsxfun replacement for ndgrid`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25885889/3293881) could be other option.

Comment: @Divakar That's true, but I don't want to sacrifice readability... performance, I'd definitely go down that route.

Comment: Hey @rayryeng, a small clarification that I noticed. So in my original problem, what I am doing is, I'm checking if there is at least one pixel that is black and if so, I increment count and move to the coordinate. I'm actually not counting up how many pixels there are. Also, what does `coords` represent?

Comment: @Jonathan That wasn't in your original code.  There's nothing about "moving" in the original code you had.  For the other point, that was also a typo.  It should be `coord`.

Comment: But in my original code, I'm checking if it's there at the location, and regardless, I'm moving on to the next coordinate. Sorry, if this point didn't come through. By "moving" I mean iterating to the next coordinate.

Comment: The code you wrote checks all coordinates in the `coord` array.  I'm doing the same thing.

Comment: Yep exactly, but the variable `count`, in your version, holds a count of how many pixels in the neighborhood has a certain value correct? I just want to check if there is even evidence of one pixel holding that value. If so, I increment count and move on to the next coordinate. Does that help?

Comment: So what you are saying is that if there is at least one pixel in the neighbourhood that is black, just increment the count by 1... and not the total number of black pixels?

Comment: Yep, that's what I was trying to get at. Sorry about the confusion. I'll edit the OP to make it more clear

Comment: @Jonathan OK, yeah that's easy to do.  Let me modify my post.

Comment: @Jonathan Done.  Very minor edit.  Required only modifying the last line.  Let me know if this is what you need!

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**The proposed solution:**

```
fc = repmat(-5:5,11,1);
I = (fc.^2+fc'.^2)<=25;
fc_x = fc(I);
fc_y = fc'; fc_y = fc_y(I);

for i = 1:length(x_coord)
    x_toCheck = fc_x + x_coord(i);
    y_toCheck = fc_y + y_coord(i);
    I = x_toCheck>0 & x_toCheck<=yourImageWidth;
    I = I.*(y_toCheck>0 & y_toCheck<=yourImageHeight);
    x_toCheck = x_toCheck(logical(I));
    y_toCheck = y_toCheck(logical(I));

    count = sum(img(x_toCheck(:),y_toCheck(:)) == 0);
end
```

---

If your img function can only check one pixel at a time, just add a `for loop`:

```
for i = 1:length(x_coord)
    x_toCheck = fc_x + x_coord(i);
    y_toCheck = fc_y + y_coord(i);
    I = x_toCheck>0 & x_toCheck<=yourImageWidth;
    I = I.*(y_toCheck>0 & y_toCheck<=yourImageHeight);
    x_toCheck = x_toCheck(logical(I));
    y_toCheck = y_toCheck(logical(I));
    for j = 1:length(x_toCheck)
        count = count + (img(x_toCheck(j),y_toCheck(j)) == 0);
    end
end
```

---

**Step-by-step:**

You first need to get all the coordinates within 5 pixels range of the given coordinate.

We start by building a square of 11 pixels in length/width.

```
fc = repmat(-5:5,11,1);
fc_x = fc;
fc_y = fc';
plot(fc_x,fc_y,'.');
```

[image]

We now need to build a filter to get rid of those points outside the 5-pixel radius.

```
I = (fc.^2+fc'.^2)<=25;
```

Apply the filter, so we can get a circle of 5-pixel radius.

```
fc_x = fc_x(I);
fc_y = fc_y(I);
```

[image]

Next translate the centre of the circle to the given coordinate:

```
x_toCheck = fc_x + x_coord(i);
y_toCheck = fc_y + y_coord(i);
```

You need to check whether part of the circle is outside the range of your image:

```
I = x_toCheck>0 & x_toCheck<=yourImageWidth;
I = I.*(y_toCheck>0 & y_toCheck<=yourImageHeight);
x_toCheck = x_toCheck(logical(I));
y_toCheck = y_toCheck(logical(I));
```

Finally count the pixels:

```
count = sum(img(x_toCheck,y_toCheck) == 0);
```

Comment: When I tried your solution, I get the following error: 
`Error using  + Integers can only be combined with integers of the same class, or scalar doubles.`

`Error in count_EGFR_ecDNA (line 26) x_toCheck = fc_x + x_coord(i);`

Comment: Nvm, I fixed it by typecasting both to int32. Um, what is the point of `fc_y = fc';`

Comment: ANd if I have to change the neighborhood size, would I just change the 5 to my new radius, and the 25 to the radius^2?

Comment: @Jonathan, `fc_y = fc'` creates a y matrix. `fc = repmat(-5:5,11,1);` creates a 11-by-11 matrix whose rows are `[-5, -4, -3,..., 4, 5]`. Transpose `fc` creates another 11-by-11 matrix, whose columns are `[-5; -4; -3;...; 4; 5]`. Let `x=fc` and `y=fc'`, we creates a 11-by-11 square whose corners are `[-5,-5]`, `[-5,5]`, `[5,5]` and `[5,-5]`.

Comment: @jonathan,"ANd if I have to change the neighborhood size, would I just change the 5 to my new radius, and the 25 to the radius^2?" Yes. But you need to be aware of precision error when doing [floating points comparison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985#Comparing_floating-point_numbers). Therefore, instead of having `radius^2`, it is better to have `radius^2+0.0000001`.